# Copy/rename multiple files using regular expression (shell script)

Tags: shell-script, sed, file-management, rename

I have a collection of files matching a pattern such as 'assignment02.cc', 'assignment02.h', 'assignment02.txt', etc. I would like to copy/rename these files into 'assignment03.cc', 'assignment03.h', 'assignment03.txt', and so on.

I suspect this should be straight forward using a shell script and sed. So far I have:

```
OLD_NO=$1
NEW_NO=$2

echo "Moving from $OLD_NO to $NEW_NO"

for name in assignment$OLD_NO.* ; do
  newname=$(echo $name | sed 's/\(.*\)$OLD_NO\(.*\)/\1xx$NEW_NO\2/')
  echo "$name -> $newname"
  # mv -v $name $newname
done
```

Unfortunately the way I am invoking sed always returns the input string `$name` and doesn't actually do the regex find/replace.

Note: Looking on the internet there is a `rename` command which has this functionality, but that isn't available on my MacBook.

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes.  If you have single quotes around the sed command, then `$OLD_NO` and `$NEW_NO` won't get expanded.

Comment: `newname=$(echo $name | tr $OLD_NO $NEW_NO)`

Answer (score 5):

Using sed here introduces more complexity than it's worth. Use the shell's built-in text manipulation features. For example, `${name#assignment02}` strips the prefix `assignment02` from `$name`.

```
for name in assignment02.*; do
  mv "$name" "assignment03${name#assignment02}"
done
```

The double quotes are not necessary if you are sure the file names contain no shell special characters.

If you have zsh available, its `zmv` function is helpful for these kinds of renamings.

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(assignment)02.(*)' '${1}03.$2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Youre already thinking too complex

```
rename 02 03 *02*
```

'rename' replaces the first arg ('02') with the second arg ('03') in the name of all files given on arg3 or after (*02*)

Comment: The `rename` command with this syntax is a Linux utility, not available on OSX (and not even available by this name on most Debian and Ubuntu installations).

Comment: Ah, didnt know you were on osx, bummer

Comment: Rename is a perl script, so it will probably run on OS X. Found it here using google: http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
for ext in {cc,h,txt}
do 
  echo mv assignment02.$ext assignment03.$ext
done
```

In the long run: Try to get 'rename'

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do it is:

```
ls -1  | sed "s/\(.*\)\..*$/mv '&' '\1.txt'/" | sh
```

Comment: [Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). And generating a shell script is a sure way to shoot yourself in the head. Vault Boy's question contains a reasonable approach on the shell side, just missing the right sed incantation and some quoting.